# Help Converting to First Logic Order Representation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm studying AI and am having some issues understanding FOL. I need help in  converting these examples into FOL with each statement having 2 variants. One with using the ∀ and the other  with the ∃ symbols:

These are the examples and my attempts:

> (i) All parrots are birds and all birds are animals.
>
> > a) ∀x, ((Parrot(x) ⇒ Bird(x)) ∧ (Bird(x) ⇒ Animal(x)))
> >
> > b) ∃x, (Animal(x) ⇒ Bird(x)) ∧ ∃x, (Bird(x) ⇒ Parrot(x))
>
> (ii) All plants are green or brown.
>
> > a) ∀x, Plant(x) ⇒ Green(x)  ∨ Brown(x)
> >
> > b) ∃x, ((Plant(x) ∧ Green(x)) ∨ (Plant(x) ∧ Brown(x)))
>
> (iii) No birds are reptiles.
>
> > a) ∀x, Bird(x) ⇒ ¬Reptiles(x)
> >
> > b) ¬∃x, Bird(x) ∧ Reptiles(x)
>
> (iv) Some students are not smart.
>
> > a) ∀x, Students(x) ⇒ Smart(x)  ∨ ¬Smart(x)
> >
> > b) ∃x, Student(x) ∧ ¬Smart(x)
>
> (v) Not all students are smart.
>
> > a) ∀x, Students(x) ⇒ Smart(x)  ∨ ¬Smart(x)
> >
> > b) ∃x, Student(x) ∧ ¬Smart(x)
>
> (vi) The widow slaps every woman who does not slap herself.
>
> > a) ∀x, ((Woman(x)∧ ¬Slaps(x,x))⇒ Slaps(Widow,x)
> >
> > b) ∃x (Widow(x) ∧ (∀(y), Woman(y)  ∧ ¬Slaps(y,y) ->  Slaps(x,y)))

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Your first sentence says that every parrot is both a bird and an animal.  It says nothing about other birds being animals.  For the existential form of your sentences, the idea is this: if all elements of a set have a property, then there exists no element of that set that does not have that property.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. Doesn't i)1) relay what the sentence means? Doesn't it already imply that parrots are animals if all parrots are birds?

Comment: An eagle may be a plant according to your sentence.  You should say "For all $x$, if $x$ is a parrot then it is a bird, and if $x$ is a bird then it is an animal."  The latter part then also applies to those $x$ that are not parrots.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do I put that info into a single First order logic statement? Do i put ∀(x), Parrot(x) -> Bird(x) ∧ [∀(x),Bird(x) -> Animal(x)] ?

Comment: Yes, you can use two quantifiers in your sentence, or you can use just one.  In English, it's OK to repeat "and for all $x$," and maybe it's clearer, but it's not necessary in this case.  With two quantifiers it is as if you went through all $x$ twice, each time asking one question.  With one quantifier, you go through all $x$ once, asking two questions for each of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do i put ∀(x), Parrot(x) -> Bird(x) ∧ [∀(x),Bird(x) -> Animal(x)]?

Right idea, but you need to be precise about the scope of the quantifier. One standard convention is to always use brackets around the quantified statement:

> $\forall x\ ( Parrot(x) \to Bird(x) ) \land \forall x\ ( Bird(x) \to Animal(x) )$.

Note that under this convention the "$\land$" has lower priority than the "$\forall x$".

This accurately translates the English sentence. There is an equivalent alternative alluded to by *Fabio Somenzi*, but it does **not** accurately reflect the English sentence:

> $\forall x\ ( ( Parrot(x) \to Bird(x) ) \land ( Bird(x) \to Animal(x) ) )$.

Actually what you need to learn is **not** how to translate English into first-order logic! Surprised by what I'm saying? Well what you need to learn is what **exactly** the sentences in first-order logic mean. So look at the definition of the **meaning** of "$\forall x\ ( \cdots )$" and "$\cdots \to \cdots$" and carefully think through what the above two sentences **mean**. Once you know precisely how to interpret every sentence in first-order logic, translating an English sentence into first-order logic becomes very straightforward; you simply construct the desired sentence to match the meaning you want to convey.

Taking (iii) as an example, you would have to ask yourself what it actually means. Well does it say something about every bird? Or does it say something about some birds? The answer will tell you which quantifier you need. You will also naturally see that "not all ..." can always be translated as "$\neg \forall \cdots$" or "$\exists \cdots$". The former corresponds more closely to the original form, while the latter corresponds to what you will get by following the kind of reasoning I showed above.

The English of (vi) is a little tricky to interpret, so the right way is to first decide what you think it **means** before attempting to translate it to first-order logic. Is "the widow" meant to convey that there is a unique object that is a "widow"? If so, then you would first have to say "there is an object that is a widow and is equal to any object that is a widow." in first-order logic. This may not be what you want. Another way is if you already have a constant symbol "widow", and if so you can just use that constant in your first-order sentence. As for "slap", it is a verb that takes a subject and object. Ignoring tense, "$x$ slaps $y$" is an assertion so we could capture "slap" by a $2$-input predicate-symbol. You have to precisely specify in your answer which input is for the subject and which input is for the object. The assertion is clearly saying something about every woman. In particular, for every woman $x$, it asserts that $widow$ slaps $x$ if ...

[Update]

I won't give direct answers to your whole list of attempts, but I'll point out the general mistakes. Under normal circumstances it is impossible for a sentence of the form "$\forall x\ ( \cdots )$" to say the same thing as a sentence of the form "$\exists x\ ( \cdots )$". The former **means** "Every $x$ ..." while the latter **means** "Some $x$ ...". That is why I said you must learn the exact meaning of first-order sentences **first**, before any attempts to translate from any other language to first-order logic. Also, to convert one quantifier to the other, we can simply analyze the **meaning** of the quantifiers. "$\forall x\ ( P(x) )$" is false exactly when there is some object $x$ such that "$P(x)$" is false, which is exactly when "$\exists x\ ( \neg P(x) )$" is true. And in general a sentence "$Q$" is false exactly when "$\neg Q$" is true. Putting these together will give you a systematic reasoning to convert each $\forall$-expression to an equivalent one using "$\exists$". Use the same reasoning on "$\forall x\ ( \neg P(x) )$" and you will get a systematic conversion of each $\exists$-expression to an equivalent one using "$\forall$".

[Second update]

**(i)(b)** Your attempt says "there is an $x$ such that ...", which as I said cannot be correct because (i) only makes claims about parrots and birds and does not even claim that there is anything at all. (i) says "given any parrot, it is also a bird". Think of it as a game. If you claim that (i) is true, then no matter what parrot I give you, you can convince me that it is a bird. It is the same as claiming that there is no parrot (that I can give you) that (I can convince you) is not a bird. Convert this into first-order logic.

**(ii)(b)** Same problem as above. Same solution. At the end you can also notice that "not ( X or Y )" is the same as "neither X nor Y" which is the same as "not X and not Y".

**(iii)(b)** It is correct, and I believe you got it after going through my previous explanation. That is precisely the same reasoning you need for the above two, but hopefully my above explanation helps further clarify them.

**(iv)(a)** Your attempt says "given any $x$, if $x$ is a student then $x$ is either smart or not smart". This is trivially true and not what you want. You only want to claim that **some** students are not smart. What is the opposite of this? The claim that every student is smart. You want the negation of the opposite claim.

**(v)** See above reasoning.

**(vi)** (a) is correct, and I think you it's because you actually did understand my explanation. (b) is not correct for the same reasons as the above.

Also please try your best to understand the explanation given in my first update, because it would explain why "$\forall x\ \neg ( \cdots )$" is equivalent to "$\neg \exists x\ ( \cdots )$".

Comment: So which one should i use?       ∀x (Parrot(x)→Bird(x))∧∀x (Bird(x)→Animal(x)).
or      
∀x ((Parrot(x)→Bird(x))∧(Bird(x)→Animal(x))) ?

Comment: @KimberlyJames: Do you understand precisely what both of them mean? If so, then choose whichever you like; there may be many different ways to convey the same meaning, but some have greater correspondence to a particular English sentence than another. If not, then you need to learn the meaning of sentences in first-order logic first.

Comment: ok thanks..i think i'm starting to understand...but the last question (v). Any ideas on that one?

Comment: @KimberlyJames: The last in your list is (vi) about a widow; is that what you want to ask about? I'll add a bit on that to my answer since the English is a bit tricky to interpret.

Comment: thanks @user21820. Is this a possible answer for vi? ∃x (Widow(x) ∧ (∀(y), Woman(y) ∧ ¬Slaps(y,y) -> Slap(x,y))) .

Comment: @KimberlyJames: "the widow" in English means that there is only one widow, so if you have a predicate "$Widow$" then you need to say "there exists unique $x$ such that $Widow(x)$ and ..." In symbols we can write "$\exists! x\ ( Widow(x) \land \text{$x$ slaps every woman who does not slap herself} )$", but you should know precisely how to express it using ordinary quantifiers, as described in the first part of my last paragraph. An easier way would be to use a constant-symbol "$widow$" and just say "$\text{$widow$ slaps every woman who does not slap herself}$". [continued]

Comment: [continued] That inner part you have there is a reasonable interpretation, namely "$\forall y\ ( Woman(y) \land \neg Slaps(y,y) \to Slaps(widow,y) )$". Note that this does not specify whether $widow$ slaps women who **do** slap themselves. However, note that my original interpretation was that it was an "if and only if" rather than an "implies". I think both are possible in English, so you've to pick the one you think the book intended. This is why in mathematics we don't use full natural language because it is ambiguous.

Comment: So is this a wrong representation? ∀xy, ((Woman(x)∧ ¬Slaps(x,x)),Widow(y)  )⇒ Slaps(y,x)

Comment: @KimberlyJames: The sentence in your last comment says "Every widow $y$ slaps every woman who does not slap herself." As I said, "the" in English means there is exactly one. You don't say "the book on the table" if there is no book there or if there is more than one book there. I think I see your problem; you think that "widow" should refer to all widows. In natural language nouns are bound by the context; "the widow" can only be uttered in a context where the audience can identify a unique person under discussion who is "widow".

Comment: okay so i would go with something like what you suggested. I'm not sure my assignment allows for the ∃!x symbol.  
So just to clarify, this is a possible answer right?: ∀y (Woman(y)∧¬Slaps(y,y)→Slaps(widow,y)) . Also i've updated my original question to include the results of my efforts...please let me know if they are correct or possible responses. Thanks! I will update the last one once i find out the second version. Thanks!

Comment: @KimberlyJames: Yes it is a possible answer, **as long as you also** specify the intended meaning of "$widow$" as a constant-symbol referring to ... Remember that without such specification, the first-order sentence cannot capture the meaning of the English sentence. We could very well use "$\forall x\ ( A(x) \land \neg B(x,x) \to B(c,x) )$" as long as we say that "$A(x)$" means "..." and "$B(x,y)$" means "..." and "$c$" means "...".

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Can you please look over my solutions to the set? I've updated my main question to include my efforts. Please let me know if they are correct. Would really appreciate that. Thanks!

Comment: @KimberlyJames: I had already updated my answer. Read it carefully and follow the instructions before amending your attempts, then you should be able to get them all by yourself.

Comment: okay so basically when we use the universal quantifier, we can make a similar statement using the existential but a negative form? Could you let me know which ones in particular, I should amend? Thanks

Comment: @KimberlyJames: If you have understood my answer, you should know precisely where you are wrong, and also the correct method to do the translation.

Comment: Like I said I am self studying ai this semester and have no one to help me out besides books and tutorials. I'm trying my best to understand what you said but I still don't understand it fully. It would have been really good to know the specific questions I answered wrong. But oh well :/

Comment: @KimberlyJames: Then ask to clarify what I said in my post, rather than just attempting to guess your way to the right answer. The goal is to get to the point where you do not need a teacher to check your answers, which of course means you must be able to tell whether an answer is correct or not with absolutely certainty. If you don't get many points in my post, ping me in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic and we'll continue there.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm not able to post in the chat room due to having only recently joining  stack exchange and low rep. I understand the meanings of the quantifier symbols but I still have problems applying it. That's why I was looking for proper answers to my set so I can apply to future questions. Could you please clarify from "Also, to convert one quantifier to the other, we can simply analyze the meaning of the quantifiers. "∀x (P(x))∀x (P(x))" is false exactly when there...onwards " you kinda lost me there. Thanks

Comment: @KimberlyJames: You need to revise the meaning of the quantifiers. "forall x ( P(x) )" is true exactly when every object satisfies P, and false otherwise. That means it is false exactly when some object does not satisfy P. There is no way to explain this step any further. I can't add you to the chat room because it says you're suspended. So why were you suspended?

Comment: I do not even know I joined like a week ago o.o

Comment: @KimberlyJames: If you still don't get it, find me in the logic chat-room. Last time there was some weird glitch that prevented me from giving you write-access, but I got Daniel Fischer to help.