# Understanding the use of existential quantifier with conditional statement

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I stumbled across this solution on the forum and had trouble understanding one part of the explanation.

Angus St. (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/652222/angus-st), English to predicate logic, URL (version: 2019-03-12): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3144648

[image: cropped explanation by the solution provider]

shouldn't the translation be:

**There is at least one person who is happy only if they are a man**

since this is a conditional statement? or is there something I am not understanding correctly?

Comment: "Some Men are Happy" is the same as "There is someone that is a Man **and** is Happy".

Comment: Right, that would be a translation for $\exists x, M(x) \and H(x)$. But if you were to translate $\exists x, M(x) \implies H(x)$ how would you do so?

Comment: @M.Shin It would translate as "There is something such that **in case** it is a man then it is happy", which is different from saying that "There is something such that it is a man **and** it is happy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\exists x. M(x)\implies H(x)$ reads: There exists a person such that if they are a man, they are happy.

An easier way to say this is: **there is a person who is happy when they are a man**.

They *may* still be happy when they are not a man $(F\implies T)$,

but if they *are* a man then they are happy $(T\implies T)$.

Likewise, when they are *not* happy, they are not a man $(F\implies F$),

but they are never *unhappy* when they are a man $\neg(T\implies F)$.

---

You can also do this:

$$\exists x.M(x)\implies H(x)\quad\to \quad\neg\nexists x.M(x)\implies H(x)\quad\to\quad\neg\forall x.\neg(M(x)\implies H(x))\\\equiv\neg \forall x.M(x)\land\neg H(x)$$

**Not every person is unhappy when they are man.**

---

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume $\exists x: \neg M(x)$, then we immediately have $\exists (x):[M(x)\implies Q(x)]$ for *any* unary predicate $Q$ regardless of its truth value.

(Applying an existential quantifier to a conditional, though technically valid, is NOT to be recommended. The result is really quite meaningless.)

Using a form of natural deduction, we have (where '|' = OR-operator):

[image]